# What's the difference between the various red-dot sights in battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

I've noticed there are several different "red-dot" sights in battlefield 3:

- KOBRA (RDS)
- PKA-S (Holo)
- Reflex (RDS)
- Holographic (Holo)

and maybe some more, not sure. But all of the above are available for my M416.

Apart from slightly different reticles (eg circle or dot), are there any other differences that actually affects gameplay?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Kobra sight is a russian red dot sight, and the Reflex sight is an american red dot sight.

The PKA-S is a russian holographic sight, and the Holographic is an american holographic sight.

- Holographic sights have a more open sight line but you aim down the sights slightly slower than red dot sights.
- Red dot sights are more confined, but aim down the sights the quickest of any scopes.

Holographic (Holo)

[image: Holo scope in Battlefield 3]

Kobra (RDS)

[image: Kobra scope in Battlefield 3]

Reflex (RDS)

[image: Reflex scope in Battlefield 3]

M145 (3.4x)

[image: M145 scope in Battlefield 3]

PK-A (3.4x)

[image: PK-A scope in Battlefield 3]

PKA-S (Holo)

[image: PKA-S scope in Battlefield 3]

PSO-1 (4x)

[image: PSO-1 scope in Battlefield 3]

All the above screenshots were taken at roughly the same 145 meter position from a capture point, so they should reflect equal distances.

Comment: This was much worse in the Beta, but the Holographic sight's bright red ring would actually glow inside the subway making it rather hard to see what was behind it. I avoided it for that reason. My favorite is probably the PKA-S, it gives a great FOV and zooms just the right amount, and the circle with dot is very functional. But all my weapons end up with IRNV 1x on it once it's unlocked.

Answer (score 2):

Just preference. Certain ones are unlocked first on particular weapons. There are no game-play advantages aside from preference. I personally like the Kobra and the Holographic. The PKA-S sits high on the gun and I don't care for that.